# How to start ct_logs in common_test

Tags: erlang, rebar3, common-test

I want to print some message in my test suite use `ct:print`, but when i run the test suite use `>rebar3 ct`, the console raise a warning as `ct_logs not started` and then an ERROR REPORT was print.

The ERROR REPORT as below:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 17-Oct-2019::12:17:11.297864 ===
** Generic server test_server_ctrl terminating 
** Last message in was {'EXIT',<0.306.0>,
                           {noproc,
                               {gen_server,call,
                                   [test_server_io,
                                    {set_job_name,undefined},
                                    infinity]}}}
```

How can i start the ct_logs to print message in test suite?